# angular.module(...).decorator is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-decorator

I'm about to tear my eyes out over this really confusing issue, I'm trying to apply a simple decorator to the `$route` service but I keep getting an error saying that `angular.module(...).decorator` is not a function, which doesn't make sense because I've used this in other projects and it has worked just fine..

How can the decorator no longer be exposed on the `angular.Module`? Doing `$provide.decorator` doesn't work either because `$provide` isn't defined, but how am I supposed to inject it when the decorator is written outside of any other code..

What can be wrong here?

```
angular.module('core').decorator('$route', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {

    $delegate.getRouteProp = function(path, prop) {

        var result = null;

        angular.forEach($delegate.routes, function(config, route) {

            if (path === route) {
                result = config[prop];
            }
        });

        return result;
    };

    return $delegate;
}]);
```

Comment: Which Angular version do you use ?

Comment: @Zakaria I'm using 1.3.0

Comment: What version of angular are you using? If its from a CDN then please provide the link.

Comment: decorator is supported only from v1.4

Comment: Updated to 1.5.0, got screwed by the angular-route module that was depending on 1.3.0. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Please provide as an answer for others in the future.